# Map is not loading in Map api v2

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I am trying to run the sample maps from android-sdk/extras/google-play-services/maps
I have done everything correct but not getting the things working.
When I run the map application MAP is not loading and rest of things working fine, even when I click on the map its giving me the longitude and latitude but not showing the map.
I have provide my own api key in manifest.mxl file.

Any hint...please....help!!!

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- End of copy. -->
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/demo_title" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDEqBupCeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BasicMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/basic_map" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/camera_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CircleDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/circle_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EventsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/events_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/groundoverlay_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LayersDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/layers_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/locationsource_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/marker_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/options_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/polygon_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/polyline_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/programmatic_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/uisettings_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/raw_mapview_demo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RetainMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/retain_map" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/multi_map_demo" />
</application>
```

And rest of the things are same as in sample provided by google.

Comment: please show your manifest, your layout and the activity where your map is defined.

Comment: API key problem? I've had some issues with it and it did not throw an exception - it just wouldn't load the map tiles if the key was not set up properly in the Developer Console. It did throw an exception if the key was not set up at all, but threw none when the key was set for a different development environment (different machine + application)

Comment: When I run the app, some times I get a message in error log red in color "Google map api authorization failed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the API key is not registered well.

Note :

- **The new version map api will only show on real device , not on emuators**
- **The Google maps app must be updated in real device.**

Follow this steps :

1.The manifest declaration is given as per Google MAPS API v2.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your api key" />
```

2.The map api key is created using instructions on google api console https://code.google.com/apis/console

3.[Enabling the maps v2 as suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjFYx.png)

4.If the problem persists , even the above checkmarks are good to go..
I would on api key .. Also try with my own api key as  `AIzaSyBzKvzJjmXJ-XXXXX-XXXX`

Comment: Your API key wouldn't work for him, unless you share your keystore with him.

Comment: Hey this key worked for me, Nice thanks man...I have done something wrong with the api key

Answer (score 0):

You have to export signed app. The map only show when the apk is signed

Comment: Not really. If you have an API key for your debug keystore, it should show up with unsigned apks as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem and for me it turned out that the Maps Api required around 5-10 minutes of settling time after the first request ever. After this, the maps continued to load fine.

Answer (score 0):

try the process at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614946/Android-google-map-api-v2-setup
seems to work fine for me

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.